# Unable to update global variable inside a function and call it outside it (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I've read some other questions about this topic and many say that if I declare the variable `varA` outside my function (in de global scope), it is a global function, and so it is accessible for any function to use and update, right?

Now, I have this example where I declare a variable outside a function, alter it inside the function, but when I call it outside the function, it displays as `undefined`, where if I'm to call it inside the function, it is altered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var varA;

    $(function() {

        varA = 'varA has been altered!';

        alert(varA); //displays 'varA has been altered!'

    });

    alert(varA); //displays 'undefined'
});
```

This does not seem logical to me: when I alter a global variable, shouldn't the second `alert();` display the value of `varA`?

What is a workaround for this problem? How can I alter a global variable inside a function and get that value outside the function?

Cheers

**EDIT:**

I need to be able to access `varA` in more than one function, so it needs to be declared before the `$(function() {});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there's a race condition for accessing `varA`: if the code below the `$(function() {});` runs before the code inside the function, then it will not be defined.

In this case, `$(document).ready()` is the same thing as `$()`, so the `document` should already be ready inside the function. Thus, you can just run

```
$(function() {
    var varA;

    varA = 'varA has been altered!';
    alert(varA); //displays 'varA has been altered!'
});
```

This isn't an issue with scoping: here's an example where the scoping is similar, but the race condition is removed, so the code will work:

```
$(function() {
    var varA;
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.then(function() {
        varA = 'varA has been altered!';
    }).then(function() {
        alert(varA); //displays 'varA has been altered!'
    });

    def.resolve();
});
```

Comment: As `varA` is declared inside the function, is it still accessible at the global scope? Can I use it outside the function?

Comment: No, you cannot, because variables are bound to function scopes. If you wanted to access it outside of the function, declare it outside.

Comment: When I declare `varA` literally above the function, it still shows as undefined (`var varA ; $(function() {...})`)

Comment: Yes, because as I've mentioned, the issue here has nothing to do with scope, and everything to do with execution order.

Comment: Then I don't think I quite understand your answer. When `varA` is defined outside the function, it will show as undefined, due to the racing condition, but how can I get this to work, then?

Answer (score 0):

As @mc10 mentioned this is primarily happening due to the race condition for accessing `varA`. This is happening because `$(document).ready()` waits for the `readystatechange` event to fire as being ready before callback gets called, however it also runs `setTimeOut` to check if the `readystatechange` event has already fired.

Thus any code like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    a();
    $(b);
    c();
});
```

Will execute in order

1. a
2. c
3. b

Answer (score 0):

By default, javascript variable get 'undefined' as the value untill they have been assigned some value. in this case your inner function is not getting execute first and out alert gets execute first and at that time value of the variable is 'undefined' so you gets the same.

to avoid this you may try as below.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var varA;

        (function () {

            varA = 'varA has been altered!';
            console.log(varA); //displays 'varA has been altered!'

        }());
        console.log(varA); //displays 'varA has been altered!'
    });
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the "()" in 3rd last line ?